# Using Castle DynamicProxy to initialize a constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

How to use *Castle DynamicProxy* to initialize a constructor with parameters? In this case `MyClass(int)`.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(){}
   public MyClass(int p1){}
}
```

Currently, `CreateClassProxy()` initializes `MyClass()`.

Comment: And I'm using Castle.Core.3.2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateClassProxy` has a lot of overloads. Including one where you pass parameters in an `object` array. This should work for you:

`generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(MyClass), new object[] { (int)2 });`

Here is the official signature:

`public object CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, object[] constructorArguments, params IInterceptor[] interceptors);`

Comment: The second parameter of CreateClassProxy() is for interceptors and not for parameters!

Comment: Adjusted my answer: There is an overload that takes the parameters.

Comment: he he! I was using CreateClassProxy<TClass>() which has only 2 overloads.